# Add If Statement To Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am running an `Insert Into` statement in my stored procedure that is receiving data from a `Table Value Parameter`  I just realized I need to 1st verify that the data does not already exist in the table before doing an insert so I am attempting to alter my procedure to this

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[CMT]
(@TempTable AS dbo.TableValue_ET READONLY)
AS
BEGIN

if b.[empID] NOT IN (Select [empID] FROM [Habib].[dbo].[SE])
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [Habib].[dbo].[SE]([empID],[POD],[empNotes],[hiredate],[terminationdate],[terminationtime],[address],[city],[state])
  SELECT
  [empID]
  ,[POD]
  ,[empNotes]
  ,convert(varchar(10), [b].[hiredate], 101)
  ,convert(varchar(10), [b].[terminationdate], 101)
  ,[terminationtime] = LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [b].[terminationdate], 100), 7))
  ,[address]
  ,[city]
  ,[state]
  FROM @TempTable b
END

END
```

However, when I attempt to save this updated syntax I get an error of

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateShippingExceptions, Line 7
>   The multi-part identifier "b.empID" could not be bound.

What must I change so that I can 1st check if the `empID` already exists in the table before inserting it?

Comment: That needs to be your where clause, not a separate if -- but using exists is probably a better idea

Comment: @JamesZ - how would I use exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic form is:

```
INSERT dbo.table
(
  cols
)
SELECT 
  cols
FROM @tvp AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.basetable AS b WHERE b.key = t.key
);
```

In your case, that would be:

```
INSERT INTO [Habib].[dbo].[SE]
(
  [empID],
  [POD],
  [empNotes],
  [hiredate],
  [terminationdate],
  [terminationtime],
  [address],
  [city],
  [state] /* why do people prefer horizontal scrollbars to vertical ones? */
)
SELECT 
  [empID],
  [POD],
  [empNotes],
  convert(char(10), [b].[hiredate], 101),
  convert(char(10), [b].[terminationdate], 101),
  LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [b].[terminationdate], 100), 7)),
  [address],
  [city],
  [state]
FROM @TempTable AS b
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM [Habib].[dbo].[SE] AS se
    WHERE se.empID = b.empID
);
```

One thing you need to find out, though, is if users enter existing `empID` values here and expect to update existing employees with new information for the other columns... if so, you're throwing their updates away without telling them.

Comment: This is strictly for inserting *new* only - updates are done in a different way.  However, than you for pointing that out.